# There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code Forbidden

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

PROBLEM: When i try to access bot using WEB Embedded code IFrame.

Sample Embedded IFrame :`<iframe style='min-width: 400px; width: 100%; min-height: 500px;' src="https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/intermediatorbotsample2019?t=ew0KICAiYWxnIjogIlJTMjU2IiwNCiAgImtpZCI6ICJSNHZYc3c3bGFUbjFaa25SUUJ1VlBGWno3WE0iLA0KICAieDV0IjogIlI0dlhzdzdsYVRuMVprblJRQnVWUEZaejdYTSIsDQogICJ0eXAiOiAiSldUIg0KfQ.ew0KICAiYm90IjogImludGVybWVkaWF0b3Jib3RzYW1wbGUyMDE5IiwNCiAgInNpdGUiOiAiR2hxaDZibGtvd0kiLA0KICAiY29udiI6ICI5SzhDbmxFMHA1bDZJVEphYVA4Sk1JIiwNCiAgIm9yaWdpbiI6IFsNCiAgICAiaHR0cHM6Ly9iNDM5YzRjMi5uZ3Jvay5pbyIsDQogICAgImh0dHA6Ly9iNDM5YzRjMi5uZ3Jvay5pbyIsDQogICAgImh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lnczc2Nob29scy5jb20iDQogIF0sDQogICJuYmYiOiAxNTQ5ODY5NDUyLA0KICAiZXhwIjogMTU0OTg3MzA1MiwNCiAgImlzcyI6ICJodHRwczovL3dlYmNoYXQuYm90ZnJhbWV3b3JrLmNvbS8iLA0KICAiYXVkIjogImh0dHBzOi8vd2ViY2hhdC5ib3RmcmFtZXdvcmsuY29tLyINCn0.h4iKrAZnZ3xN0czwtz09Qg8KnqkJpRLZ17Lxcp7oTuUMvhXiBc0tgDOBDQOIQgBPqe3xGWPiDROe3HvcmFS5BXow7KnwqvaLQLOle2SHo_YphJTtnXncHJXta8zmFJY_EPdLHcteUHlO4vjA1JM9WFfVnrPX5C4MxE9Zb-L8WNd0GhG7K4R40MZ7hdUcxaLahrLjog5e0C_FOlf46LP8qWf6LAKoqnqCwhPoPhbRcSh7sWUSW7pDbj-CPSiy6c7d0l9lBi-J8nWksof_6UYD9qxh4D7c4dc_y12zGh0yHwoQrteOf_T9JuQ31PkzRQdI94iep0AlB7c-NsNAkJylnw"></iframe>`

Microsoft azure bot channel issues error say's: Http status code forbidden.
[(image) Log's Azure channel show error issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWC4J.png)

- Successfully tested the bot locally using the bot emulator(with deployed bot 
  api endpoint)
- Successfully tested on emulator with bot Api and Password

Comment: Are you generating the token after every conversation, because a single token will work only for one conversation, to start new you'd have to call the API again to get the new code.

Comment: Yes i am generating token for each instance of  embedded Bot IFrame conversation. using new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "https://webchat.botframework.com/api/tokens", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'BotConnector ' + 'YOUR SECRET HERE');
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

    function processRequest(e) {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4  && xhr.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        document.getElementById("chat").src="https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/lucas-direct-line?t="+response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you've got there, it looks like a token. The webchat iFrame uses the secret given on the channel configuration page of Azure:

```
    <iframe src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/JJQnANodeBot?s=YOUR_SECRET_HERE'  
style='min-width: 400px; width: 100%; min-height: 500px;'></iframe>
```

That part you have

```
intermediatorbotsample2019?t=
```

needs to read:

```
intermediatorbotsample2019?s=
```